# Getting Infinite Loop Issue. Process Terminated due to StackOverflowException?

Tags: c#, exception, stack-overflow, infinite-loop

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{

class class1
{
    protected internal string inf1()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\n......inf1() \n");

        return inf1();
    }
}




class class2 :class1
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        class1 c1 = new class1();

        class2 c2 = new class2();

        Console.WriteLine(c1.inf1());

        Console.WriteLine(c2.inf1());

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Getting Infinite Loop Issue. Process Terminated due to `StackOverflowException` ?

How to prevent the code from looping infinitely ?

Comment: Yes, inf1 is called recursively and therefore resulting in an infinite loop, so a stack overflow is expected behavior. What is your question or what do you not understand?

Comment: Your code clearly has an infinite recursion, method inf1 always executes itself, what exactly do you expect to happen?

Comment: What's the point of this? Are you trying to call a method in the parent class or what?

Comment: Yes I am trying to call a method in the parent class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `class2`, you are calling `Console.WriteLine(c1.inf1());`.

So `class1.inf1` should return a string as you are trying to output it to the console.

However, `class1.inf1()` recursively calls itself with no exit and does not return a string.

So I think this may be what you are trying to accomplish:

```
protected internal string inf1()
{
    return "\n......inf1() \n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks For your help.Now I have understood the reason behind infinite looping.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here :

```
protected internal string inf1()
{
    Console.WriteLine("\n......inf1() \n");
    return inf1();
}
```

This method return a call to itself everytime which mean it will be called indefinitely. The problem with that is that a program before it enter a method add to the stack the current position on memory it is on so that when a method return it can go back to that place and continue from there, but that stack is not infinite and so with your problematic method it become full and the program then crash because without a stack it cannot continue to function.