# Turtle Graphics - Process terminated due to StackOverflowException

Tags: c#, recursion, stack-overflow, turtle-graphics

I am trying to prepare a Turtle graphics solution in C#. Everything is working fine but it ends in Process Terminated due to StackOverflowException. I checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26016613/getting-infinite-loop-issue-process-terminated-due-to-stackoverflowexception)
and 
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46520739/c-sharp-process-is-terminated-due-to-stackoverflowexception)
where the issue is of getter setter or infinite loop. But I dont have any of this condition in my code. I am a newbie in C#. 
Below is my code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TurtleGraphics
{
    class Program
    {/**
     * Directions: 0 right, 1 down, 2 left, 3 up
     */
        private static short direction = 0;
        private static bool penDown;
        private static int turtleX = 0, turtleY = 0;
        private static int[,] floor = new int[20, 20];


        public static void Main(String[] args)
        {
            initFloor(floor);
            //Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
            printMenu();
            int nextCommand = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            while (nextCommand != 9)
            {
                switch (nextCommand)
                {
                    case 1:
                        penDown = false;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        penDown = true;
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        direction++;
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        direction--;
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        Console.WriteLine("How many steps do you want to move?");
                        int move = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                        if (move <= 10)
                            while (--move != 0)
                             Moves();
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        printArray();
                        break;
                    default:
                        Console.WriteLine("Unknow command, please try again:\n");
                        break;
                }
                Moves();
                Console.WriteLine("What's next?");
                nextCommand = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            }
        }

        private static void initFloor(int[,] floor)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < floor.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < floor.GetLength(1); j++)
                {
                    floor[i,j] = 0;
                }
            }
        }

        private static void printMenu()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Commands List:\n\n\t1 Pen up\n"
                        + "\t2 Pen down\n"
                        + "\t3 Turn right\n"
                        + "\t4 Turn left\n"
                        + "\t5 to 10 Move forward 10 spaces (replace 10 for a different number of spaces)\n"
                        + "\t6 Display the 20-by-20 array\n"
                        + "\t9 End of data (sentinel)Please enter a command number:\n");
        }

        private static void printArray()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < floor.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < floor.GetLength(1); j++)
                {
                    // Console.WriteLine(floor[i, j]);
                    // Console.WriteLine("  ");
                    if (floor[i, j] == 0)
                        Console.Write(".");
                    else if (floor[i, j] == 1)
                        Console.Write("*");
                    else if (floor[i, j] == 2)
                        Console.Write("T");

            }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }

        private static void Moves()
        {
            switch (direction)
            {
                case 0:
                    turtleX++;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    turtleY++;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    turtleX--;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    turtleY--;
                    break;
                default:
                    if (direction < 0)
                        direction = 3;
                    else
                        direction = 4;
                    Moves();
                    break;
            }
            if (penDown)
            {
                if (turtleX < 20 && turtleY < 20)
                    floor[turtleX, turtleY] = 1;
                else
                {
                    direction -= 2;
                    Moves();
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Any quick help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Usually any "overflow" exception means an infinite loop has occurred. Try to debug to find where it's looping too much (like millions of times...)

Comment: Also check case 5 in your main loop - if operator enters 0, move will be less than 10, your while loop will decrement that to -1 & that will not be zero - so you will end up doing 4 billion moves till the number wraps around to zero again.

Comment: Setting direction to 3 if it is less than zero is not correct: The turtle can have turned any number of steps, so direction can be any negative value, and in order to find the correct direction you must add 4 at a time, as given in my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's one obvious situation where you end up looping endlessly. Imagine you're entering the `Moves` method and `direction` is 4:

```
    private static void Moves()
    {
        switch (direction)
        {
            case 0:
                //Nope
            case 1:
                //Nope
            case 2:
                //Nope
            case 3:
                //Nope
            default:
                if (direction < 0)
                    //Nope
                else
                    direction = 4; //Okay, but it already was
                Moves(); //And call myself again
```

The code cannot make any further progress and the call stack fills up with more and more calls to `Moves()` that are never going to finish.

I can't offer a correction because I don't understand what your code is meant to be doing. Break it down into *smaller* methods with *clearer* method names and XML documentation comments that describe *what it does*. Then makes sure that the code and comments agree.

I have no idea what the *correct* operation of a method called `Moves` is.

Answer (score 0):

The default section of the switch statement in Moves should be this:

```
        default:
            if (direction < 0)
                direction += 4;
            else
                direction -= 4;
            Moves();
            break;
```

since its purpose is to wrap the direction value such that it always remains in the range 0-3.

Comment: Why the downvote? This IS the correct behavior for a turtle.